# Characterize continuous functions

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{B}=${$B_q(0,0):q \in \mathbb{Q}$} a basis for the topology $\tau(\mathbb{B})$.

How are the continuous functions $f:(\mathbb{R^2},\tau(\mathbb{B})) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\tau_e)$, with $\tau_e$ the euclidian topology.

I start seeing when the preimage of an open set in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_e)$ is not an open set in $(\mathbb{ R^2},\tau(\mathbb{B})$: for example, if $f$ got irrational values as $\sqrt(2)$ I can't find any open ball with a rational ratio that covers the preimage... so I started thinking about constant rational functions ... or functions which get only rational values... How can I move?

Comment: Just making sure, $B_q(0,0)$ is the open ball centered in $(0,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ with radius $q$? Is your basis made all of balls centered in the origin?

Comment: yes, with q a rational number

Answer (score 1):

So $\{(0,0)\}$ is dense in $\tau(\mathbb{B})$ , as all non-empty open sets contain $(0,0)$ (the rationals are a smoke screen).

This means that for any continuous $f$ with codomain $Y$, $\{f(0,0)\}$ must be dense in the image of $f$. An in any $T_1$ space this can only happen if the image is just one point.. So all continuous maps from your space to all metric spaces in particular are constant.

Comment: sorry but why is ${(0,0)}$ dense in $\tau(B)$?

Comment: @feddy I gave the reason right after the statement, A set $D$ is dense iff it intersects every non-empty open set.

Answer (score 0):

A space is hyperconnected when for all not empty open U,V, U intersection V
is not empty.  For example, infinite cofinite spaces are hyperconnected.
Show that your space is hyperconnected.  To answer your question,
proof the following easy theorem.

If X is hyperconnected, Y Hausdorf and f:X -> Y is continuous,
then f is a constant function.